# Performing operations on grouped rows in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe where pic_code value may repeat. If it repeats, I want to set the variable "keep" to "t" for the pic_code that is closest to its mpe_wgt.

For example, the second pic_code has "keep" set to t since it has the "weight" closest to its corresponding "mpe_weight". My code results in "keep" staying 'f' for all and "diff" staying "100" for all.

```
df['keep']='f'
df['diff']=100

def cln_df(data):
    if pd.unique(data['mpe_wgt']).shape==(1,):
        data['keep'][0:1]='t'
    elif pd.unique(data['mpe_wgt']).shape!=(1,): 
        data['diff']=abs(data['weight']-(data['mpe_wgt']/100))
        data['keep'][data['diff']==min(data['diff'])]='t'
    return data

df=df.groupby('pic_code').apply(cln_df)
```

df before

```
  pic_code      weight      mpe_wgt    keep    diff
  1234          45          34         f       100
  1234          32          23         f       100
  45344         54          35         f       100
  234           76          98         f       100
  234           65          12         f       100
```

df output should be

```
  pic_code      weight      mpe_wgt    keep    diff
  1234          45          34         f       11
  1234          32          23         t       9
  45344         54          35         t       100
  234           76          98         t       22
  234           65          12         f       53
```

I'm fairly new to python so please keep the solutions as simple as possible. I really want to make my method work so please don't get too fancy. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: To help narrow down the issue:  I'm wondering if either of your if or elif blocks are getting executed.  if you add and else to your if/elif block, and set keep to some odd value, like z, then does the data frame change?

Comment: My end goal is to remove the rows where "keep" does not equal t; is there a more efficient way to do what I'm trying to do. With my method, my next step would be to filter the df to remove all instances where "keep" = false.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is one way. Note I am using Boolean values `True` / `False` in place of strings `"t"` and `"f"`. This is just good practice.

Note that all the below operations are vectorised, while `groupby.apply` with a custom function certainly is not.

**Setup**

```
print(df)

   pic_code  weight  mpe_wgt
0      1234      45       34
1      1234      32       23
2     45344      54       35
3       234      76       98
4       234      65       12
```

**Solution**

```
# calculate difference
df['diff'] = (df['weight'] - df['mpe_wgt']).abs()

# sort by pic_code, then by diff
df = df.sort_values(['pic_code', 'diff'])

# define keep column as True only for non-duplicates by pic_code
df['keep'] = ~df.duplicated('pic_code')
```

**Result**

```
print(df)

   pic_code  weight  mpe_wgt  diff   keep
3       234      76       98    22   True
4       234      65       12    53  False
1      1234      32       23     9   True
0      1234      45       34    11  False
2     45344      54       35    19   True
```

Comment: You forgot to include logic keeping the row with the smallest distance between weights.

Comment: @MSanders, I don't think so.. that's what `sort_values` followed by dropping duplicates does. The smallest distance comes to the top after sorting and the larger ones get dropped.

Comment: the ~df.duplicated('pic_code') block will always take the first occurrence of a duplicated pic_code??

Comment: @MSanders. Exactly.

Comment: You're awesome jpp. Thanks for your help and the lesson.

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
df['keep'] = df.assign(closest=(df['mpe_wgt']-df['weight']).abs())\
               .sort_values('closest').duplicated(subset=['pic_code'])\
               .replace({True:'f',False:'t'})
```

Output:

```
   pic_code  weight  mpe_wgt keep
0      1234      45       34    f
1      1234      32       23    t
2     45344      54       35    t
3       234      76       98    t
4       234      65       12    f
```

Comment: Pretty much identical to mine but chained :). Still deserves a +1.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can try `cumcount`

```
df['diff'] = (df['weight'] - df['mpe_wgt']).abs()
df['keep'] = df.sort_values('diff').groupby('pic_code').cumcount().eq(0)
df
   pic_code  weight  mpe_wgt  diff   keep
0      1234      45       34    11  False
1      1234      32       23     9   True
2     45344      54       35    19   True
3       234      76       98    22   True
4       234      65       12    53  False
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `eval` and `assign` to execute similar logic as other answers.

```
m = dict(zip([False, True], 'tf'))
f = lambda d: d.sort_values('diff').duplicated('pic_code').map(m)
df.eval('diff=abs(weight - mpe_wgt)').assign(keep=f)

   pic_code  weight  mpe_wgt keep  diff
0      1234      45       34    f  11.0
1      1234      32       23    t   9.0
2     45344      54       35    t  19.0
3       234      76       98    t  22.0
4       234      65       12    f  53.0
```